# ¿Por que mi texto no se centra verticalmente?

Tags: html, css

tengo un problema con el texto al lado de un icono o *img*:

[image: imagen que muestra el problema]

lo que pasa es que quiero mostrar ese texto como por el centro de la imagen, pero que quede así, al lado de la imagen. Lo he intentado hacer con `vertical-align: middle` pero no funciona como verán a continuacion.

**Código HTML:**

```
<span>
    <img src="res/img/code-outline-icon.png" alt="icono de un codigo en una hoja">
    <h3>Lenguajes de programación y tecnologías</h3>
</span>
```

**Código CSS:**

```
.body-briefcase span {
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-top: 10%;
}

.body-briefcase span img {
    height: 48px;
    width: 48px;
}

.body-briefcase span h3 {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 1em;
}
```

Por favor si alguien tiene alguna idea o la solución del problema que me la pase que con gusto la recibo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que estás usando flex, agrega la propiedad align-items de css a tu span

```
.body-briefcase span {
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    align-items: center; /* esto alinea el contenido al centro verticalmente */
}
```

Comment: Si me sirvió mucho, gracias amigo

Answer (score 1):

Te comento lo siguiente:

- El primer detalle que deberías corregir es que un [elemento en línea](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements) como en este caso lo les el `span` no debe ser contenedor de un [elemento en bloque](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) como lo es en este caso el `h1`
- Lo siguiente es que podría ser mas conveniente mover al título dentro de un contenedor propio y así poder acomodarlo mas fácilmente

  - Con este paso puedes de manera *aislada* desplazar al centro verticalmente al texto con respecto de su contenedor sin que la imagen se vea en cierto momento *comprometida*

Ejemplo:

```html
    <style>
      :root {
        --acomodo-elementos: flex;
      }
      .contenedor-principal {
        display: var(--acomodo-elementos);
      }
      .contenedor-principal__imagen {
        border: 1px solid; /*esto no es necesario*/
        height: 150px; /*esto no es necesario*/
        width: 150px; /*esto no es necesario solo son para ejemplificar*/
      }
      .contenedor-principal__texto {
        align-items: center;
        border: 1px solid;
        display: var(--acomodo-elementos);
      }
    </style>
    <div class="contenedor-principal">
        <img class="contenedor-principal__imagen" src="ruta_imagen">
        <div class="contenedor-principal__texto">
          <h3>Lenguajes de programación y tecnologías</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: ok muchas gracias por la información